# RTK query skipping body response when statusCode is 401 (4xx range)

Tags: rtk-query

I'm migrating fro RTK + axios to RTK query and I'm having one issue when the response is 401. The endpoint returns a body json with the following:

```
{
  timestamp: 123,
  status: 401,
  message: 'Some useful message to the UI',
  path: '/my-path-2'
}
```

The problem is that RTK query simply **ignores the body response**. It's skipped. With axios it works fine.

Code for RTK is this:

```
export const userApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'userApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `api/`,
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    loginUser: builder.mutation({
      query(data) {
        return {
          url: 'login',
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
        };
      },
      async onQueryStarted(args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const res = await queryFulfilled;
          // do the rest of stuff.
        } catch (error) {
          // when the response is > 400 it falls here...
          console.error('error', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
          // returns {"data": undefined, "error": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", "originalStatus": 401, "status": "PARSING_ERROR"}
        }
      },
    }),
});
```

[image: See how the responses looks like]

The tool I'm using to debug those requests are Reactotron.

[image: The two requests compared in markdown format]

How can I get the body response to be returned in the RTK query? Am I missing something here?

============
**EDIT:**
As I'm still haven't figure out how to put the fetchBaseQuery to return the body response, I found out that I can replace it with axios by replacing the fetchBaseQuery() with a custom axiosBaseQuery()

```
const axiosBaseQuery =
  (
    { baseUrl }: { baseUrl: string } = { baseUrl: '' }
  ): BaseQueryFn<
    {
      url: string
      method: AxiosRequestConfig['method']
      body?: AxiosRequestConfig['body']
      params?: AxiosRequestConfig['params'],
    },
    unknown,
    unknown
  > =>
  async ({ url, method, body, params }) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios({ url: baseUrl + url, method, data: body, params });
      return { data: result.data };
    } catch (axiosError) {
      const err = axiosError as AxiosError;
      return {
        error: {
          status: err.response?.status,
          data: err.response?.data || err.message,
        },
      };
    }
  };
```

after replacing the fetchBaseQuery with a custom axiosBaseQuery it works. I cant grab the body response.

Comment: You are getting an error here because some of your code tries to read something here - `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"`. This is caused by your code. Maybe show that code?

Comment: No. It's not because of that. Nothing is executed before and after that request. In other words there's no .length being executed.

Comment: Can you show the full endpoint definition please? I have an idea what might cause this, but need to verify.

Comment: That createApi() is posted in full. There's nothing else in addition to the code I posted. Then only thing I didn't post is the call to that query which is just `loginUser({ email: 'ma@ma.com', senha: '123' })`; Basically, as you can see in the update I posted, I think this is a problem with fetch() running under the hood. Replacing it with axios() call instead solved the problem. Also, after the `const res = await queryFulfilled;` there's just a console.log(res);

Comment: It seems that [this call](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/query/fetchBaseQuery.ts#L353C26-L353C41) returns `undefined`, which usually doesn't happen with fetch. Generally, fetch will see a "401" as successful as a "200" or a "999" response - it doesn't care. It's the `validateStatus` status function of RTK that classifies "errors" here on a completely irrelevant code path.
So here you either have a CORS problem, or maybe a fetch polyfill that changes some behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the response with the call redux-toolkit/packages/toolkit/src/query
/fetchBaseQuery.ts! It makes more sense to me now.

Comment: fetch has 2 methods, and you can assess your body in the second.
but with Axios it is the first then. just double-check.